# Condição em view não funciona

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Eu estou verificando se minha ViewBag vem algo

Então faço o seguinte:

```
@if (ViewBag.Itens != null)
{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.Itens)
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ItensCheck" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" />
                    @item.Text
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw("Não existe Itens cadastrado.")
}
```

Quando ele vem a lista de Itens, ele percorre o meu foreach e faz tudo conforme quero, mas quando ele não tem nada, ele não faz a condição else que desejo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converta sua ViewBag para um tipo forte antes de comparar:

```
@{ 
    var itens = ((IEnumerable<TipoDaLista>)ViewBag.Itens); 
    if (itens != null) 
    {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ainda não funciona, eu envio um List<SelectListItem> e mesmo assim, não consigo fazer com que o else retorne aquela mensagem

Comment: @Rod Já tentou inspecionar o `ViewBag.Itens` em Debug?

Comment: Ele não vem null, mas com Count()>0 também não funciona..

Comment: Cigano, eu criei uma variável @ { var Itens =  .. e depois fiz as condições e loop nela e deu certo, só edita sua resposta para que eu possa assinalar, afinal, sem sua resposta eu naõ iria ter resolvido

Comment: @Rod Editei a resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Use Object.ReferenceEquals(null,  ViewBag.Itens).

A ViewBag e do tipo dynamic,  como esse tipo é variável não existe um comparador nativo como string.equals.